# Data cleaning using grepl and getting error "unsupported matrix index in replacement"

Tags: regex, r, dataframe

I have a number of day's worth of travel information, and a tick box where if they didn't do anything, they should tick it.

So I need to clean out any days where the person gave information but also ticked the 'did nothing' box.

Here is some example data for two days (Monday and Tuesday):

```
test <- structure(list(Mon_a = c(NA, 5L, NA, NA, 3L), Mon_b = c(NA, 5L, 
NA, NA, 3L), Mon_c = c(NA, 2L, NA, NA, 1L), Mon_d = c(NA, 2L, 
NA, NA, 1L), Mon_Nada_e = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA), Tue_a = c(NA, 
4L, 5L, NA, 3L), Tue_b = c(NA, 3L, 5L, NA, 3L), Tue_c = c(NA, 
2L, 2L, NA, 1L), Tue_d = c(NA, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L), Tue_Nada_e = c(1L, 
NA, 1L, 1L, NA)), .Names = c("Mon_a", "Mon_b", "Mon_c", "Mon_d", 
"Mon_Nada_e", "Tue_a", "Tue_b", "Tue_c", "Tue_d", "Tue_Nada_e"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

So, I want to write one function that I can just apply to each day.  I came up with the following code, which *almost* does what I want, although perhaps it isn't very nice or tidy:

```
day <- "^Mon" # (this would be passed as an argument in the function)

daynadacol <- colnames(test)[grepl(paste(day,"_Nada_e", sep = ""), names(test))]  # gives the name of the column for that day which is 'did not travel'
daycols <- colnames(test)[(grepl(day, names(test)))] # can probably do these two steps with a -grep?
daynotnada <- daycols[!(daycols%in%daynadacol)]

test[,daynotnada][test[,daynadacol]==1 & !is.na(test[,daynotnada])] <- NA
```

But, I also want the 'did nothing' column to be NA, since I can't trust anything that person put down on that day - I don't want to count it as did nothing, I want to count it as missing data.
So I thought, hey I can just tell it to replace for all the day columns like this:

```
test[,daycols][test[,daynadacol]==1 & !is.na(test[,daynotnada])] <- NA
```

But alas I get an error: `Error in`[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, test[, daynadacol] == 1 & !is.na(test[,  :   unsupported matrix index in replacement`

Is it something really obvious that I'm doing wrong?  Is there a way to fix this so it works?  Probably this is just really ugly code :( and there's a much better way of doing the whole thing anyway..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simpler way to solve your problem:

```
day <- "^Mon"

daycols <- grep(day, colnames(test), value = TRUE)
daynadacol <- grep("_Nada_e", daycols, value = TRUE)
daynotnada <- setdiff(daycols, daynadacol)

idx1 <- !is.na(test[[daynadacol]])
idx2 <- !rowSums(is.na(test[daynotnada]))

test[idx1, daynotnada] <- NA
test[idx2, daynadacol] <- NA

#   Mon_a Mon_b Mon_c Mon_d Mon_Nada_e Tue_a Tue_b Tue_c Tue_d Tue_Nada_e
# 1    NA    NA    NA    NA          1    NA    NA    NA    NA          1
# 2    NA    NA    NA    NA         NA     4     3     2     1         NA
# 3    NA    NA    NA    NA          1     5     5     2     2          1
# 4    NA    NA    NA    NA          1    NA    NA    NA    NA          1
# 5     3     3     1     1         NA     3     3     1     1         NA
```

Comment: I want to keep the 1s in the did nothing column where there are already NAs though - that isn't invalid data.  So there should still be 1s in column Mon_Nada_e, rows 2-4.

Comment: Nearly there :D  so there should be an NA in the second row nada_e column... is there a way to put some kind of conditional when assigning idx along the lines of `any(!is.na(test[,daynotnada]))` or somethign like that?

Comment: Sorted!  Works exactly how I want, thank you so much!  Sorry if my explanation of what I was looking for wasn't very clear.